# Unable to share project in Azure Form Recognizer studio. "Please make sure you have the permission to access Storage Account"

Tags: azure, azure-form-recognizer

When I try to share the project in the form recognizer studio I get an error: "Cannot share project. Please make sure you have the permission to access Storage Account."
[image]
[image]

I have permissions on the storage container. What additional permissions / roles do I need in order to be able to share a project? (generate a token)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is JP from Form Recognizer PM team. Would you kindly check if your storage account VNet is enabled or if there are any firewall constraints, the project can't be shared. If you want to bypass those restrictions, ensure that those settings are turned off.

Thanks!

Comment: This was confirmed in the support ticket I opened: "When the storage account has v-net and fire wall enabled, it blocks the project from being shared or triggers an error during sharing/generating token."

Answer (score -1):

Kindly check,
If you should be assigned either the "Contributor" or "Owner" role for the Form Recognizer service. This role provides the necessary permissions to manage the Form Recognizer resources and share projects.

Comment: I have the contributor role on the entire subscription. Opening projects is working fine, sharing isn't working

Comment: Kindly check this once the Share Project Permission - In the Form Recognizer Studio, the owner needs to explicitly share the project with Azure AD identity of member for Sharing the project will grant you access to work on the project and generate a token.

Comment: What is "Share Project Permission" ? Is that a role in Form Recognizer? I cannot find it.

Comment: Sharing projects generates a token that other users can "import". Why does it say I don't have permission on the storage account? I have the contributor role.